# AngularJS & PrerenderIO, prerenderReady isn't working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, prerender

I'm setting the prerenderReady flag in my html (inline)

```
<script> console.log(Date()); window.prerenderReady = false; </script>
```

and setting it to true in my angular controller upon $http get success like this:

```
Post.getAll($stateParams.order, $stateParams.type, 10)
            .success(function(response) {
                Post.setPosts(response.data);
                vm.nextUrl = response.next_page_url;
                vm.loading = false;

                $window.prerenderReady = true;
                console.log(Date());
                console.log($window.prerenderReady);
            });
```

the difference between the inline date() and the success of the request is 3secs

nevertheless the prerender server reaches over 11500ms gets timed out and renders only the page's header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the comment from prerender logger and found out prerender had a problem with socket.io

I didn't knew what could be the problem since I am running prerender server and Socket.io server from different nodes and on different ports.

after trying to upgrade phantomjs from 1.9 to 2.0 with no avail
miraculously I tried replacing the socket.io cdn link in my index.html file
with inline script.

Now the pages are rendered perfectly :)